# Make an element from an external JS script clickable

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how you can link to a element that is loaded from an external javascript (it's like a chat widget hosted on an external website). I googled a lot of threads on stack overflow with similair issues but none of the code worked as expected.

The code that appears in the header of my website;

```
  var shadow = 'box-shadow: none;' 
  var customStyle = '.ExampleLauncherContent__bubble {' + shadow + '}';            
  var myExample = new ExamplePopup({
    index: 'https://example.com/example.html',
     launcherOptions: {
     style: customStyle,
  }
  });
```

Then the element is styled like this on the custom CSS section of my website

```
.ExampleLauncher:before { 
    content: "Example"; 
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    opacity: 1; 
    color: #333; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

Now I would like to make the entire CSS styled element clickable with a link, but I am not sure how to integrate the code, example i found in other threads that did not work as expected (or maybe I implemented wrong)

```
<script>
a onclick="jsfunction()" href="#"
</script>

<script>
div.ExampleLauncher("click", function() {
   alert("You clicked this div");
});
</script>

<script>
$(".ExampleLauncher").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $(".ExampleLauncher").click();
  }
});
</script>

<script>
$(".ExampleLauncher").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
    });
</script>

<script>
$('.ExampleLauncher').onclick="myExample.open()    
});
</script>
```

Regarding recent comments, this is script used to trigger the chatbot popup with a textlink

```
   myLandbotpop.on('landbot-load', function(){
   var buttonOpen = document.getElementsByClassName("openbot")[0];
   buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", myLandbotpop.open)
```

Comment: None of these `<script>`s really make any sense. At best, the fourth one - but did you include a copy of jQuery in your page?

Comment: How is that `new ExamplePopup` defined, where does it come from? Please tell us more about it - maybe link the library that you are using.

Comment: Hi, I got these scripts from related threads, I think jquery is included somewhere but in the header only this related script is included, this is also the chatbot I based the script on. Link to the library https://static.landbot.io/landbot-widget/landbot-widget-1.0.0.js, I replaced the terms with example, but the terms in the OP stand for LandbotLauncher, and LandbotPopup

Comment: What I just want is that the ExampleLauncher (actually the LandbotLauncher) CSS styled element triggers the bot popup, when using a text link the follow script is used tot trigger this (added to OP), but I am not sure how to implement this in an element